# Setting text in activity using Button

Tags: android

I was wondering what is the correct way to set the text of a TextView after a button has been pushed? I currently have an app that would change the text every time the activity was created (but for now it only sets the text as one value for testing purposes):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mama);
    TextView joke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    joke.setText("This is a test");
    Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(JokesMamaActivity.this, JokesMamaActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

How would I be able to set the text without creating a new activity, and have the ability to continually change the text after the button has been clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
...
public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView joke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    joke.setText("Text after click");
}
...
```

Of course, there is no real need to search for `joke` `TextView` again, you can make it `final` after first `find()`.

Comment: Thanks! For a second, I thought that once I clicked the button, it wasn't working for me when I switched the text, but the cause was my faulty logic.

Comment: OK, BTW, you can accept an answer if you feel that it is right one :)